# How to deal(catch) with tensorflow warnings to avoid CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0)Failed to set cuDNN stream

Tags: tensorflow

I in trying different hyperparameters using grid search while building models in tensorflow. Hence, sometimes, I got the following warning:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:211] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.50GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```

Hence, I would like to skip training the model causing this warning.

Additionally, I found out that similar warning is causing the following error:

```
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:231] Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0)Failed to set cuDNN stream.
```

Please note that I have tensorflow-gpu 1.12 built from binaries; windows 10; GPU: GTX 1080 Ti and cuda v9.0

Answer (score 0):

My problems are solved after updating cuDNN from v7.4.2.24 to v7.5.0.56